# Merge source files with destination, replacing older ones

Tags: shell, osx

I'm looking for the linux equivalent of the DOS command:

```
xcopy from/* to/* /s/e/d/y
```

Which copies over all new files and only replaces old ones. I'll be running this from the terminal of a Mac OSX computer.

Comment: If `rsync` is available on your platform, go for it!

Comment: "copies over all new files and only replaces old ones" - so it copies all files from directory from/, and overwrites files of same name that exist already in directory to/ ?

Comment: are `/s` and `/e` not contradictory?

Comment: @Joachim It copies over any files that don't already exist at the target directory, and replaces older files at the target.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use find for this:

```
cd from
find * -print0 | cpio -pdmv0 to/
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `cp -f from/* to/`. But I don't know the meaning of all the options to your DOS command; maybe you have to choose additional options here, `man cp`.